# React Consume value from custom render function with typescript get error is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, swiper.js

I tried to create a reusable swiper component with Next.js 13 (App Router) v13.4.12 and also use TypeScript. I get an error when I try to "consume" data from the component props, which is a custom function render for the parent.

First I create the interface `IItem` & `ICarousell` like this also use generic for reusable

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";

export interface IItem {
  [key: string]: undefined
}

export interface ICarousell<T> {
  items: Array<T | IItem>,
  children?: ReactNode,
  customRender?(el: IItem | T): T | ReactNode
}
```

Then I created the reusable Swiper component like this, using the Interface that I created before.

```
"use client"
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react"
import { ICarousell } from "./Carousell.types";

import 'swiper/css';

export default function Carousell<T> ({ children, items, customRender, ...props }: ICarousell<T>) {
  return (
    <Swiper
      {...props}
    >
      {items.map((item, idx) => (
        <SwiperSlide key={idx}>
          <>
            {customRender ? customRender(item) : item }
          </>
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}

      {children}
    </Swiper>
  )
}
```

After that, I tried to use the `Carousell` component on the Home page, but I got an error similar to the image I attached below.

```
import { Carousell } from "@/core/components";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Carousell
        items={[
          1,
        ]}
        customRender={(element) => (
          <div>{element}</div>
        )}
      />
    </main>
  )
}
```

[image: Error Sample]

And I tried to edit my generic just for testing like this

```
export interface ICarousell<T> {
  items: Array<T | IItem>,
  children?: ReactNode,
  customRender?(el: any): ReactNode // Use "any" for the parameter type
}
```

I tried not to change the custom render type with `any`, and I tried using a React fragment tag, it worked.

```
<Carousell
  items={[
    1,
  ]}
  customRender={(element) => (
    <>{element}</>
  )}
/>
```

but if I tried again to add the `div` inside the `fragment` tag like this, it wouldn't work again.

```
<Carousell
  items={[
    1,
  ]}
  customRender={(element) => (
    <>
      <div>{element}</div>
    </>
  )}
/>
```

The main goal is array should be able to accept any type of array, such as `object`, `string`, or `number`. And the custom render can render the value from the array

I'm not sure, but I think the problem is the parameter type. I don't know how to deal with it. Hopefully you guys can help me. Thanks in advance. Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Just a question, I am actually just thinking out loud: When you are rendering the "element", you are basically placing the object `{ name: "3"}` in the `div` . Shouldn't this be `element.name` ?

Comment: yes if the array is array of objects it work. it wont work when i fill the array with string or number only. my bad, I will update the question

Comment: I played around a little and it seems like the types do not work well with each other. I tried a very basic typeguard and that made it work instantly. You may have to refine this to suit your needs: `<div>{element instanceof Object ? element.name : element}</div>`

Comment: `IItem` is just a normal object, what are you looking to do with it in terms of rendering? For e.g., you might be wanting to just display the the object in a json format, or the item represents something, like a book, and you'd want to show a card of that book in the Carousel. The issue is coming from the fact that a normal object isn't a react node, it has to be converted to a react node first, before rendering. So, `customRender` should always return a `ReactNode` and if not, then there should be an internal rendering function, that checks to see if the items provided are react nodes or not.

Comment: Based on that, it'll either convert the data to react nodes for rendering or just return them.

Comment: I tried to always return the react node using fragment tag, and it works, but when i tried to add another tag let say div etc. it start causing error

Comment: Based on my code, it means that the custom render always returns a React node. Maybe the related conversation will move to @LickingFilth's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There are two aspects that you need to consider.

##### The first one is that React is not capable of rendering objects.

When you attempt the following code snippet:

```js
  <Carousell 
    items={[{name: 'Name1'}, {name: 'Name2'}]} 
    customRender={(item) => item}
  >
    teste
  </Carousell>
```

TypeScript (TS) will generate an error because it always expects a ReactNode but receives an object.

ReactNode refers to a Union type, which is shown in the image below:

[image]

##### The second aspect is that the IItem type seems unnecessary.

Consider the following examples:

```
  // Your <T> (item) will be the "number" so IItem is not used
  <Carousell 
    items={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
    customRender={(item) => item} //item is typed as a number
  >
    teste
  </Carousell>


  // Your <T> (item) will be "{name: string, age: number}" so IItem is not used
  <Carousell 
    items={[{name: "User One", age: 18]} 
    customRender={({name}) => {name}} //the fn param is an object, name is a string
  >
    children
  </Carousell>
```

Hence, you can eliminate the IItem type and let the generic function handle the typing.

The final result will be:

```
export interface IItem {
  [key: string]: undefined;
}

export interface ICarousell<T> {
  items: Array<T>;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  customRender?(el: T): React.ReactNode;
}
```

You can [check the result here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/polished-sky-ymjzf5)

Answer (score 0):

Since you’re using arrow function on customRender

You could modify ICarousel interface like this

```
export interface ICarousell<T> {
  items: Array<T | IItem>,
  children?: ReactNode,
  customRender?: (el: IItem | T) => ReactNode
}
```

Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types

Comment: Thank you, I already tried it before and no effect

Answer (score 0):

The key is to make sure that the `customRender` fn can handle any type of item in the array and always return a ReactNode (since it's being rendered in JSX).

The `customRender` fn takes an item of type `T` and return a `ReactNode`.

```
export interface ICarousell<T>{
  items: Array<T>,
  children?: ReactNode,
  customRender?(el: T): ReactNode
}
```

Make sure that `customRender` fn is used to render each item. If it is not provided just render the item directly (assuming it is a primitive type like string or number).

```
export default function Carousell<T>({children, items, customRender, ...props }: ICarousell<T>){
  return(
    <Swiper {...props}>
      {items.map((item, idx)=>(
        <SwiperSlide key={idx}>
          {customRender ? customRender(item) : item}
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}
      {children}
    </Swiper>
  );
}
```

You can use the `Carousell` with arrays of any type. If you're using an array of objects just provide a `customRender` fn to dictate how each object should be rendered.

```
// Example array of numbers
<Carousell
  items={[1, 2, 3]}
  customRender={(element) => <div>{element}</div>}
/>

// Example array of objects
<Carousell
  items={[{ name: 'John', age: 25 }, { name: 'Jane', age: 30 }]}
  customRender={(element) => <div>{element.name} is {element.age} years old</div>}
/>
```

Comment: seems like it not reusable when u start use array of object, the reason i put the `IItem` interface is for reusable purpose. So the component can recieve any type of array

Comment: Ok, I get it. You want Carousell component to be flexible enough to handle arrays of any type. I'll adjust my answer

Comment: Amazing! it works!, but the `{customRender ? customRender(item) : item}` block say `Type 'string | number | boolean | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | Iterable<ReactNode> | PromiseLikeOfReactNode | T | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode | ((slideData: SlideData) => ReactNode)'.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode | ((slideData: SlideData) => ReactNode)'.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.ts(2322)`

Comment: btw I tried to add an extends to `T` on the Carousell component like this `Carousell<T extends string | number>` and now the error move to the custom render with array of objects value

Comment: Error is because TypeScript can't guarantee that the type T is a valid ReactNode. When you're using generics, TypeScript tries to infer the type based on the usage. In this case, it's having trouble because T could be anything technically. I think Ive found the solution but it's not the most elegant one ;D

Comment: Instead of directly rendering the item, you can check its type and decide how to render it: 
`{items.map((item, idx) => (
  <SwiperSlide key={idx}>
    {customRender ? customRender(item) : typeof item === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(item) : item}
  </SwiperSlide>
))}`
This convert objects to strings using JSON.stringify(). Its not pretty but it should prevent TypeScript errors. Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. I don't know if my idea is the best way, but I was just wondering if we can transform/change the custom render to required on TypeScript when the item type is object. 

Comment: Ok, how about this: `export interface ICarousell<T> {
  items: Array<T>,
  children?: ReactNode,
  customRender: T extends object ? (el: T) => ReactNode : undefined | ((el: T) => ReactNode)
}`
With this setup, if `T` is an object, `customRender` becomes required function.

Answer (score 0):

React don't render object values. It only renders string, numbers, null and JSX.Element which are basically react elements.

so the mistake in your code is:

```js
"use client"
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react"
import { ICarousell } from "./Carousell.types";

import 'swiper/css';

export default function Carousell<T> ({ children, items, customRender, ...props }: ICarousell<T>) {
  return (
    <Swiper
      {...props}
    >
      {items.map((item, idx) => (
        <SwiperSlide key={idx}>
          <>
            {customRender ? customRender(item) : item /*
            // this will throw an error sooner or later, 
            // because objects can't be rendered. 
            */ } 
          </>
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}

      {children}
    </Swiper>
  )
}
```

instead, you can do:

```js
"use client"
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react"
import { ICarousell } from "./Carousell.types";

import 'swiper/css';

export default function Carousell<T> ({ children, items, customRender, ...props }: ICarousell<T>) {
  return (
    <Swiper
      {...props}
    >
      {items.map((item, idx) => (
        <SwiperSlide key={idx}>
          <>
            {customRender ? customRender(item) : defaultRender(item)/* define this somewhere */} 
          </>
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}
      {/*OR*/ customRender && items.map((item, idx) => (
        <SwiperSlide key={idx}>
          <>
            {customRender(item)} 
          </>
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}

      {children}
    </Swiper>
  )
}
```

---

The same applies to your custom render function, you can't pass item or element as object. If you inspect ReactNode, you see it only accepts: string, number, JSX.Element and null.

So you can't pass object as ReactNode.

so you do the following:

```js
import { Carousell } from "@/core/components";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Carousell
        items={[
          1,
        ]}
        customRender={(element) => (
          <div>{
                /*use only string or number values, not objects*/
                element.name
           }</div>
        )}
      />
    </main>
  )
}
```